# How to remove submenupage from WordPress Backend Parentpage upload.php?

Tags: wordpress, backend, submenu

i am trying to remove a submenu_page from WordPress Parentpage upload.php.

This is the url of the submenu_page i want to remove:

```
http://localhost:8080/wp-admin/edit-tags.php?taxonomy=ressorts&post_type=attachment
```

[image]

It is found under media ("Medien" in german). I tried to remove it with

```
remove_submenu_page('upload.php', 'edit-tags.php?taxonomy=ressorts&post_type=attachment');
```

But it didn't work. I was able to remove every menu_page und submenu_page (from posts) i want but only for media it is not working.

Hopefully someone knows the answer. It is confusing me. :)

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution, which is working for now:

You just need to get the global array variable $submenu and remove the element specific element from it. See the code below.

It not really feels ideal and has more something of a temporary fix.

```
global $submenu;
unset($submenu['upload.php'][15]);
```

Hopefully someone might find this usefull or have a better solution.

Comment: Removing a subpage from Profile seems to be working completly different. It is a mess!

Comment: My mistake. Seems i just forgot to set the priority for the hook function, which worked out before the WordPress Update.